# Connecting to an existing database in Netbeans

Tags: mysql, netbeans

I'm working in NetBeans 6.8 and I'm trying to create new connection using MySQL to an existing database. Does the .mdb file need to be in a specific location? It tells me that it cannot establish the connection.

Answer (score 1):

.mdb is an extension of a Microsoft Access database file, not MySQL. You need a different driver and you're not likely to get a platform-independent open source implementation.